# Embeddable HTML Image Slider

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I'm trying to make an image slider using Adobe Dreamweaver. Is there anywhere where I can find a customizable image "slideshow" in which there are arrows on the side which will allow the user to scroll through the images freely?

It can't be one where I need to download an extension first please.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try this http://unslider.com/ You can set arrows to navigate the images on the slider. Read its documentation for applying the arrows.